# Insert smiley text and this playing the images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Please guys, I have a problem. I created a page where smileys texts can be inserted in the textarea when the the image is clicked and when the submit button is clicked the form is submitted through ajax method, here is the code which works very fine:

```
    <form id="my_form">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="open" placeholder="Comment..."></textarea><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="post" name="post" value="<?php echo $my_id; ?>" />
    <span id="form_span"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="comment_send" value="COMMENT" /></span><div style="display:none;" id="form_progress"><img src='progress-dots.gif' /></div>
    <div id="form_error" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:;" style="float:right;margin:5px 5px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" onclick="document.getElementById('form_error').style.display='none'">x</a>Please make a Comment!</div>
    <div id="emoji" class="emoji">
    <a href="javascript:;" title=":glad;"><img title="glad" border="0" src="emojis/smiley2.png" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" title=":joy;"><img title="joy" border="0" src="emojis/smiley3.png" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" title=":jeer;"><img title="jeer" border="0" src="emojis/smiley43.png" /></a>
    <a href="javascript:;" title=":angry;"><img title="angry" border="0" src="emojis/smiley76.png" /></a>
</div>
    </form>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if($("#comment").val() == "")
                  {
                      $('#comment').focus();
                    document.getElementById('form_error').style.display='block';
                  } else {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "comment_send.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        document.getElementById('form_error').style.display='none';
                        document.getElementById('form_progress').style.display='block';
                        $('#form_span').html("<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='disable_comment' value='COMMENT' disabled/>");
                    },
                    success: function(status) {
                        $('#comment').val('');
                        document.getElementById('form_progress').style.display='none';
                        $('#form_span').html("<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='comment_send' value='COMMENT' />");
                    }
                });
                  }
            });
        });
    </script>
//to insert the emoji texts in the text area
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#emoji a').click(function () {
   var smiley = $(this).attr('title');
   ins2pos(smiley, 'comment');
});

function ins2pos(str, id) {
   var TextArea = document.getElementById(id);
   var val = TextArea.value;
   var before = val.substring(0, TextArea.selectionStart);
   var after = val.substring(TextArea.selectionEnd, val.length);

   TextArea.value = before + str + after;
   setCursor(TextArea, before.length + str.length);

}

function setCursor(elem, pos) {
   if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.focus();
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
   } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
   }
}
    </script>
```

And I also use the jquery `.load` function to display the comments on the same page:

```
    <div id="comment_display" style="width:250px;height:500px;overflow-y:auto;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#comment_display').load('comment_display.php')
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
```

And here is the comment_display.php page:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $comment = $row['comment'];

    echo "<p>".$comment."</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

and all this code works very fine but now my problem is I want to replace the emoji texts is been display with its own image, so I use this code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

// for :glad;
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/:glad;/g,'<img src="emojis/smiley2.png" />'));

// for :joy;
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/:joy;/g,'<img src="emojis/smiley3.png" />'));

// for :jeer;
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/:jeer;/g,'<img src="emojis/smiley43.png" />'));

// for :angry;
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/:angry;/g,'<img src="emojis/smiley76.png" />'));
    </script>
```

But when I add this last javascript code to replace the emoji texts, the emoji images that inserts the emoji texts into the textarea stops to work, if I click them it doesn't do anything

Comment: Hi you can not put/show images inside textarea instead create a editable div and style it to look like a textarea... kindly refer https://jsfiddle.net/bxfawxv8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created small demo that replace just a word

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  var txt = $("textarea").val();
  var newtxt=txt.replace(/:glad/g, '<img src="emojis/smiley76.png" />');
  $("textarea")[0].innerText=newtxt; //YOU HAVE TO SET NEW TXT IN TEXTAREA
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="5" rows="5">:glad</textarea>
<button>
  click
</button>
```

may b you have used $(body).html() thats why its not working..This may b not your answer but you can get idea what is missing in your code..